# D2L Valence - post feedback for a dropbox with no submission

Tags: php, desire2learn

I am currently implementing an app using the D2L Valence API. The goal is to upload 1 file per student (different for each student though) in some course. The file is now uploaded as a feedback for a combination of course-dropbox-student. Everything works perfectly as long as there is a submission from that student. If there isn't any - the call fails. I know this is possible to do via the UI (i.e. if I try to post a feedback through the UI for a user with no submission, it still works), but my question is would it be possible to do the same via API call. I tried simply attaching the file using [this call](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/dropbox.html#post--d2l-api-le-%28version%29-%28orgUnitId%29-dropbox-folders-%28folderId%29-feedback-%28entityType%29-%28entityId%29-attach) (the file is uploaded before doing that) or [posting a feedback](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/dropbox.html#post--d2l-api-le-%28version%29-%28orgUnitId%29-dropbox-folders-%28folderId%29-feedback-%28entityType%29-%28entityId%29) and then attaching the file to it. Nothing works unless there is a submission. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're correct that the API doesn't currently support this behaviour (submitting feedback against a dropbox with no submission). If this behaviour does exist in the WebUI, then this would run contrary to D2L's stated goal that the API should be at feature/behaviour parity with the Web UI. I would therefore encourage you to report this as a defect via your organization's ASC or partner or account manager.